# Unit tests for ASP.NET Core failing in VSTS pipeline due to HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, azure-devops, xunit, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebAPI that uses `xUnit` and `FluentAssertions` frameworks. It creates a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer` and from that server object we create an `HttpClient` using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer.CreateClient()` API.

The unit tests work great on my local Windows 10 machine using Visual Studio 2017 Pro. I committed the code, then did a pull request. The pull request automatically kicks off a build process to ensure it builds. Once it builds, it looks for then runs the unit tests. At this point it fails. I have 242 unit tests. All 242 unit test fail with the exact same error reported by the agent:

`Expected resp.StatusCode to be OK, but found TemporaryRedirect.`

All 242 unit tests make a request to the test server, so they all expect an `HttpStatusCode.OK` (or similarly expected) response. I should never expect a `HttpStatuscode.TemporaryRedirect` so I really don't want to add a test case for this.

The build server is running in VSTS as Microsoft Server 2012 R2 with Visual Studio 2017 Pro installed.

Why would the `TestServer` object return a Redirect ever?

If there is no way around this, can I force the `HttpClient` to auto-redirect when it receives this status so I only get the result of the API call?

Here is the code I am using to create the server and the client:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Path.GetFullPath("../../../../XXXXXXXXService/"))
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .Build();

_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>().UseConfiguration(config));
TestHttpClient = _server.CreateClient();
```

An example unit test that is failing:

```
private string DeriveHttpPath(string path) =>
    $"/{_rootPath.Trim('/')}/{path.TrimStart('/')}";

private static async Task<TResult> ValidateAndReadResponseAsync<TResult>(
    HttpResponseMessage resp, HttpStatusCode statusShouldBe, Func<TResult> defFactory = null)
{
    (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode ? HttpStatusCode.OK : resp.StatusCode).Should().Be(statusShouldBe);
    try
    {
        return await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResult>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return defFactory != null ? defFactory.Invoke() : throw ex;
    }
}

public async Task<TResult> GetDocumentDataAsync<TResult>(string documentId,
    string path = null, HttpStatusCode statusShouldBe = HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
        DeriveHttpPath($"{_collectionId}/{documentId}?path={path}")))
    using (var resp = await _httpClient.SendAsync(msg))
    {
        return await ValidateAndReadResponseAsync<TResult>(resp, statusShouldBe);
    }
}
```

`_rootPath` will be the root of the controller, i.e.: `/api/MyController`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you show us one of your failing _integration_ tests and your startup.cs?

Comment: added a code example. The startup.cs file is huge as it's shared between the unit test project and the main API. I am not doing any middleware or anything that would be fiddling with the http request pipeline. Just injecting some transient services.

Comment: I added some debug code -- what it's trying to do is redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. So i am going to assume it's some code in my startup.cs that forces HTTPS redirection. But why does it work locally just fine? Does `TestServer` handle HTTPS requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was because this was defined in the `startup.cs`:

```
#if !DEBUG
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
#endif
```

So when I was running the unit tests locally, it was compiled as Debug, where when it was pushed to the build server, it compiled as Release and the Https-Redirection was turned on.

I took that code out and made my WebAPI HTTPS-Only by setting it in Azure.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT : they make you wait 24 hours before accepting your own answer and I simply forgot to come back. Thanks for the reminder :)